Derivation of the width of the Kondo resonance and properties of a Lorentzian
I am working through the section in Subir Sachdev's Quantum Phases of Matter textbook on the Kondo impurity problem.
The main result is Eq. 29.46, where I can evaluate the resonance width by
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{J_K d(0)}  =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d \Omega}{\pi} A_f(\Omega) \ln \left|\frac{D}{\Omega}\right| 
 =\ln \left(\frac{D}{\Gamma_P}\right) .
\end{equation}
where the spinon spectral function is a simple Lorentzian defined by \begin{equation}
A_f(\Omega)=\frac{\Gamma_P}{(\Omega-\bar{\lambda})^2+\Gamma_P^2}
\end{equation}
I would think this is an integral of the form
\begin{equation}
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{d x}{\pi} f(x) \frac{\Gamma}{(x-x_0)^2 +  \Gamma^2} \sim f(x_0)
\end{equation}
where for small broadening, I can approximate the Lorentzian by a Dirac delta function. But this is definitely not what is done here. What mathematical trick am I missing here?
